# Flutter: realtime database querying using orderbychild() and only int value works string data not querying

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

`starCountRef.orderByChild('Series').startAt('sam').endAt('1')`

This code only work if I use int values to fetch data; string values are not fetching the data.

```
DatabaseReference starCountRef =
      FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('/Shop/qw1234/Inventory/');

bool data = false;

Expanded(
  child: FirebaseAnimatedList(
      query: starCountRef
          .orderByChild('Series')
          .startAt('sam')
          .endAt('1'),
      itemBuilder: (context, snapshot, animation, index) {
        return ListTile(
          onTap: (() {
            print(index);
          }),
          title: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  Text('Price: Rs '),
                  Text(
                      snapshot.child('Price').value.toString()),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
          subtitle: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Model: ',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    Text(snapshot
                        .child('Series')
                        .value
                        .toString()),
                  ],
                ),

              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }),
)
```

My firebase realtime database I am trying to setup a search box to search product and edit or delete them

[image]

Can any one help me? I am developing an inventory app for a shop. I am trying to make a search box so the owners can see their stock limits and item prices.

Comment: In addition to GrahamD's answer below, also consider reading [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) as using sequential numeric indexes as keys in the Firebase Realtime Database is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rather think the firebase query works in ASCII order. In ASCII order, numbers appear before letters so starting at 'a letter string' and ending at 'a number string' is likely to cause you problems.

I don't see a '1' in your example of 'Series', you aren't trying to reference the '1' child in the 'Inventory' node are you?

Comment: That seems to be the problem indeed. A good query on this data would be: `starCountRef.orderByChild('Series').startAt('sam').endAt('sam2')`, which would return the first 2 child nodes in the picture.

Comment: thank you after adding full string it worked

Comment: starCountRef.orderByChild('Series').startAt('sam2').endAt('sam2\uf8ff')
 this way the search box working perfectly